# Can intel haxm work on an amd processor?

Tags: cpu, virtualization, intel-haxm

I'm just wondering if it is worth trying to install the intel HAXM. I have an amd processor. Does the intel haxm require an intel cpu?

Thanks you!

Comment: Have you looked at the system requirements for this tool? Any such limit will be published in the system requirements by the software publisher.

Comment: this helped me find what I needed. Thanks!